# move icon to end of input html

Tags: html, angular

question mark is an angular component tooltip which  is needed to be at the end of the input I am not sure how that can be done attaching screenshot of the issue. [image]

```
    <div id="{{config.name}}" class="dynamic-field form-explorer" [formGroup]="group" [ngClass]="fieldShow" [class.has-tooltip]="config.tooltip" *ngIf="!config.isHidden">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="toggleTree()" type="button">{{"Browse" | translate}}</button>

    <tooltip *ngIf="config.tooltip" [message]="config.tooltip"></tooltip>
    <mat-input-container class="full-width">
        <input matInput [type]="'text'" [placeholder]="config.placeholder | translate" [formControlName]="config.name" [required]="config.required">
    </mat-input-container>
    <mat-error *ngIf="config.hasErrors">{{config.errors}}</mat-error>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that more of a CSS problem?

Comment: please don't provide an incomplete code snippet, people don't know your angular code, so those {{}} won't do much of help when trying to debug, try to copy the markup from the devtool after running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes indeed it was a CSS problem, I ended up using "float:right;"

```
 <tooltip style="float: right;" *ngIf="config.tooltip" [message]="config.tooltip"></tooltip>
```